# Honda Fit GP1 2013 Engine Oil Burn

Tags: engine, honda, fit

I have honda fit GP1 (Manufacture year - 2013) and well maintained. 78000km is done up to now and I normally use 10W30 synthetic oil. as I feel engine oil is burning faster than normal vehicle. After service I can run nearly 3000km without refuel engine oil. here is my problem.

last week when I drive suddenly I see engine check light turn on and in my IMA shows

> VSA warning

after that I can not drive car because when I accelerate car does not go foreword. After I carry car to technician he said that this is common problem for Honda Fit GP1 modal, you have to replace piston set and do engine overall.. :( what is the problem here and what should I do..?

Note: technician showed me spark plugs and said oil is leaked to spark plugs.
      After he washed all spark plugs, then issue was fixed.

Comment: The technician told you what the problem is... Up to you to decide if you want to do that work or get another car.

Answer (score 3):

Before you look at having any overhaul or similar done at a third party it's worth checking with your local Honda dealership as there is a [recall](https://www.honda.co.jp/recall/auto/other/170120.html) for the Fit GP1 regarding the oil consumption issue.

Basically there is a flaw in the design of the pistons which allows a dirty sludge/deposit to form on piston ring, this means the ring doesn't seal properly and oil then leaks into the combustion chamber (initially manifesting as oil consumption and ultimately misfires and a general failure to proceed).

I believe the first steps they take is to clean the pistons/rings/plugs (and then presumably cross fingers and hope it doesn't happen again) or if it reoccurs then they replace the pistons and rings with an updated design.

**Edit:**

To expand upon my earlier thoughts it's worth clarifying what the technician actually did - if they **only** cleaned the plugs then the buildup on the pistons/rings is still there and the problem **will* be back relatively soon. The pistons rings and oil return hole also need cleaning or oil will start building up on the plugs straight away.

Comment: So, basically what the technician told the OP...

Comment: @SolarMike yep but with added "why" and bonus recall info

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **@motosubatsu** for your answer. I checked with my local Honda dealer about free repair and they said that because of that Gray import there will not be free repair.. :(

I think they only clear spark plugs and did engine tune up. what is the best solution for this.. ? is it clean pistons/rings or replace them.. ?

lets say I replace those pistons and is there any chance to occur that problem again.. ? what is your suggestion about use this vehicle for long time or is it good to change vehicle. because I can not afford more repairs like this..

Comment: I have experienced the same problem and contacted Stafford Motor(Honda agent in SL) . They said that Honda has officially sent a proper modified parts to solved this problem.Now they have a permanent solution for this which is replacing rings,pistons and few other parts.Even though this is a design failure they charge this for around LKR200,000/= which is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Before spending money on any major repair. Try this:

Drain whatever engine oil is left in the engine. If you have good level of clean oil then you don't need to drain.

Fill the engine with 2 litres of flushing oil aka cheapest engine oil that you can get - it must be thin oil.

Add engine flush. I used a can of WHIZ.
Now keep your vehicle on a flat surface, and idle the engine for 3 to 5 min.

Drain oil. In my case to my horror the oil was all black.

Refill with 5w-30 synthetic oil. Do not go for thicker oil like 10w or higher. 0w 20 for areas with cold weather. I live in Karachi, Pakistan so this suits me during winters.

Enjoy your ride. Keep monitoring oil level and oil color. It should stay fresh 
Monitor your vehicle. I experienced better mileage and still monitoring oil level as it's just one day has passed.